# I am having a UserWarning: unknown class(es) when using MultiLabelBinarizer

Tags: python, multilabel-classification

I using MultiLabelBinarizer for multiclassification problem. When I transform on the test data, I got the following warning;
/local/Anaconda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/_label.py:994: UserWarning: unknown class(es) ['235', '256', '546', '425'] will be ignored
warnings.warn('unknown class(es) {0} will be ignored'.
Is there a way to avoid this warning? Will it impact the performance of my classifier?

```
mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
mlb.fit(df_train['outcome'])
y_train = mlb.transform(df_train['outcome'])
y_test = mlb.transform(df_test['outcome'])
print(y_training)
print(y_validation)
```

Answer (score 0):

That means there's classes in the test data that aren't in the training data. I suggest fitting the mlb to a combined list of both the training and test outcomes.
The performance of the classifier is affected since you have outcomes in your test data that have no instances in your training data for your model to train on.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It will impact the performance of the classifier but in a good way, given that fitting the Binarizer on training AND test data would be a form of data leakage.

I would argue against fitting on all data. The test set is a simulation of NEW data that your pipeline/model has never seen before, and therefore you would not include it.
The warning is telling you that the object is performing exactly as expected. It builds the vocabulary of the features (.classes_) and then transforms new data with that same vocabulary. If there are new features it hasn't seen, it will ignore them in the conversion and then raise the warning.